# Selection Sort Java and Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have written a selection sort code in java. I know its very elementary algorithm, but since i am learning, so wanted your input about the quality of the code. Please have a look at the code:
package selection_sort;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelectionSort {

int [] arrayToBeSorted;
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);


SelectionSort(){
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements");
    int total=scan.nextInt();
    this.arrayToBeSorted=new int[total];
    for(int i=0;i<total;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the "+i+" number of elements");
        this.arrayToBeSorted[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    
}

public void Sort() {
    int minIndex,min;
    boolean swapRequired=false;
    for(int i=0;i<arrayToBeSorted.length;i++) {
        minIndex=i;
        min=this.arrayToBeSorted[i];
        for(int j=i+1;j<this.arrayToBeSorted.length;j++) {
            if(this.arrayToBeSorted[j]<min) {
                min=this.arrayToBeSorted[j];
                minIndex=j;
                swapRequired=true;
            }
        }
        if(swapRequired) {
            swap(i,minIndex);
        }
                    
    }
    
    for(int x:this.arrayToBeSorted) {
        System.out.print(x+" ");
    }
        
    }

public void swap(int i,int j) {
    
    //System.out.println("swap called, pos="+i+"and minindex="+j);
    int temp=this.arrayToBeSorted[i];
    this.arrayToBeSorted[i]=this.arrayToBeSorted[j];
    this.arrayToBeSorted[j]=temp;
    
    //System.out.println("------------");
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SelectionSort s=new SelectionSort();
    s.Sort();
}

}
```

Also about Analysis, as selection is O(n2), is it because I am using nested for loop. Is there any tool which tells us about complexity of code .Thanks in advance and please be patient if its very naive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
int [] arrayToBeSorted;
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
```

Without any modifier, members and functions are `package-private`. Which means that they are accessible from the same package, but not by instances extending the class. That's an extremely odd thing, actually, when looking at it from an object-oriented point of view. You want to either make them `private`, or if extending classes should be able to access them, `protected`.

Same goes for the constructor.

---

```java
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements");
    int total=scan.nextInt();
    this.arrayToBeSorted=new int[total];
```

You could use a `List`/`ArrayList` instead of an array, which would mean that you can receive as many numbers from the users as they want without having to specify the count beforehand. An empty input could be used for declaring the end of the list. However, that has the downside that you must use `Integer` instead of `int`, so it' is kinda hard to tell what is better. It also has the downside that detecting an empty input is that readily available from `Scanner`, as you'd need to use `nextLine` for that, with manual conversion to `int`.

You could also emulate a `List` by dynamically growing the array. Either by doing it for every item, performance does not matter in this use-case, or by doubling the size when needed.

---

```java
this.arrayToBeSorted=new int[total];
```

You only require the `this` modifier if you have a variable with the same name in the same scope, for example in a constructor:

```java
public ValueContainer(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

It's common practice to omit `this` if not needed. If you ever find yourself in the situation that it is confusing whether an instance, static or local variable is used, you did something wrong there anyway.

---

```java
for(int i=0;i<total;i++) {
```

I'm a very persistent advocate for using "real" names for variables in loops.

```java
for (int counter = 0; counter < total; counter++) {
// or
for (int index = 0; index < total; index++) {
```

---

```java
public void Sort() {
```

The Java naming conventions state that methods/functions should be lowerCamelCase.

---

```java
int minIndex,min;
```

Personally I'd avoid declaring multiple variables on the same line. It makes it easy to miss declaration.

---

```java
boolean swapRequired=false;
```

That's a great example of a great name for a variable, thank you!

---

```java
    for(int x:this.arrayToBeSorted) {
        System.out.print(x+" ");
    }
```

That, unfortunately, is a bad name for a variable. Only use "x", "y" and "z" when working with dimensions. "value" or "number" would be a great name here.

---

Overall, it looks valid. I did not run it to test the functionality, though. What you should change is that you have logic in the constructor. Nobody expects constructors to be filled with logic, because you can't see the intent of logic from them. They should be as nothing doing as possible. That means that you should move the logic into `sort` or, even better, into `main`. Your Sorter should not be concerned with input at all, it should only be concerned with sorting values, ideally, and another class (`InputReader`?) should be concerned with getting the input. So what you could do is something like this:

```java
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    InputReader inputReader = new InputReader();
    
    int[] values = inputReader.readValues();
    
    Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
    sorter.sort(value);
    
    // TODO Print sorted output.
}
```

That also has the upside that you don't need to hold state in `Sorter` at all, which would make it thread-safe by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed review ..will inculcate these points specially the constructer one and the naming